# Replace subexpression with variable in result from Laplace transform

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement, expression-manipulation, integral-transforms

I'd like to clean up the result I obtained from an inverse Laplace transform:
[image]

First of all, I'd like to replace the square root expressions in the hyperbolic function arguments (part encircled in green) by an angular frequency expression, i.e. I want to replace the expression

```
Sqrt[-Ld2-Ld3]/(Sqrt[Cr]*Sqrt[Ld2]*Sqrt[Ld3])
```

with a variable "`w0`". Similarly, I want to replace the whole "amplitude" (part encircled in red) of the expression with a simple variable named "`Z`".

How do I do that? I'm actually looking for some way specify equations for `w0` and `Z` and make Mathematica search for the required parts in the equation itself, i.e. I'd like to specify

```
w0 = 1/Sqrt[Cr * Ld2*Ld3/(Ld2+Ld3)]
```

and Mathematica should be able to extract the required parts from the trigonometric function arguments itself and replace them. Not sure if that's possible at all though.

As a second step I want to get rid of the hypberbolic sine and cosine functions that currently have imaginary arguments and would like to use nonhyperbolic sine and cosine terms. Is there a way to get rid of them?

Comment: Try something like  ` .../. 1/Sqrt[Cr * Ld2*Ld3/(Ld2+Ld3)]->w0`